# How to renew a Vault token?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am using below command to renew the lease for my token:

```
Vault.auth_token.renew_self 3600 * 24 * 30
```

but getting the following error:

> invalid lease ID

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, adding more references would help others to follow this.